# Get primes below x

Tags: haskell, primes

I'm trying to write a procedure that returns a list of all primes below a given number.

For example:

```
Prelude>primes 8  
[2,3,5,7]
```

When I try to load the file I get `Parse error in pattern Failed, modules loaded: none.` If someone could point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

```
primes :: Int -> [Int]
primes x < 2 = []
primes x | isPrime x == True = primes (x - 1) ++ x
         | otherwise = primes (x - 1)

isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime x | x < 2 = False
          | x == 2 || x == 3 = True
          | divEven x == True = False
          | divOdd x 3 == True = False
          | otherwise = True

divEven :: Int -> Bool
divEven x | mod x 2 == 0 = True
          | otherwise = False

divOdd :: Int Int -> Bool
divOdd x num | mod x num == 0 == True
             | num <= x/2 = divOdd x (num + 2)
             | otherwise = False
```

Comment: `x == True` is the same as `x`.

Comment: Thanks Vitus. I actually had it without that earlier, but added it in when it wouldn't compile. I suppose it doesn't really make any difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A collection of small mistakes.

1. Your syntax is incorrect.

   ```
   primes x < 2 = []
   ```

   Probably you meant

   ```
   primes x | x < 2 = []
   ```

   Similarly, where you write

   ```
   divOdd x num | mod x num == 0 == True
   ```

   you probably meant

   ```
   divOdd x num | mod x num == 0 = True
   ```
2. The type signature

   ```
   divOdd :: Int Int -> Bool
   ```

   is not valid.  You probably meant

   ```
   divOdd :: Int -> Int -> Bool
   ```
3. `x` is of type `Int`, and `(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a` cannot be applied to it.  You probably mean `` num <= x `div` 2 `` or `2 * num <= x`.

   ```
   divOdd :: Int Int -> Bool
   divOdd x num | mod x num == 0 == True
                | num <= x/2 = divOdd x (num + 2)
                | otherwise = False
   ```
4. `x` is of type `Int`, not `[Int]`.  `(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]` will not apply to it.

   ```
   primes x | isPrime x == True = primes (x - 1) ++ x
   ```

   Perhaps you meant

   ```
   primes x | isPrime x == True = primes (x - 1) ++ [x]
   ```

Finally, this is a fairly inefficient way of generating primes.  Have you considered a sieve?  [Prime numbers - HaskellWiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers) may be a bit difficult for you right now, but shows many different strategies.

Comment: Thank you very much. These were indeed my problems. As you may have guessed I am fairly new to Haskell. I will look into sieve, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Probably need backtick escapes for infix use of `\`div\``

Comment: @roldugin Stack Overflow's Markdown makes it difficult to insert backticks in inline code -- works differently in questions and answers than in comments -- but I've fixed it; should be correct now.

Comment: @ephemient you can put double backticks around your inline code fragments in answers and questions, then single backticks will work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a re-write of your functions using [list comprehensions](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/List_comprehension) (also [in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Haskell)), perhaps this is more visually apparent:

```
primes :: Int -> [Int]
primes x | x<2  = [] 
         | x<4  = [2..x]
         | True = primes (x-1) ++ [x | isPrime x]
```

your `isPrime` is

```
isPrime x = x > 1 && 
          ( x < 4 || 
            and [ rem x n /= 0 | n <- 2 : [3,5..(div x 2)+2] ] )
```

[`and` is a function defined in standard Prelude](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#g:13). It will test entries in a list, left to right, to see if all are `True`. It will stop on the first `False` entry encountered, so the rest of them won't get explored.

Sometimes when the code is more visually apparent it is easier to see how to improve it.

Comment: your isPrime will check 3 conditions every time, it's better to have an infinite list of primes and take x elements from it

Comment: @Vixen it's not "mine"; :) I just wrote down the OP code in a different form which is IMO clearer and easier to see how to improve. :) you're quite right; as a standalone function it has to check them, so it should be made internal to "primes" so extra checks can be dropped, etc. etc. I wanted to provide the OP an easy starting point.